# Large White Space at bottom of website

Tags: css, wordpress

Every so often when I'm visiting my website, I notice that there is a large white space at the bottom of the site. If I refresh the page, the white space disappears and everything is normal. This is happening quite frequently now, at least once a day when I visit my site.

I have noticed this on Google Chrome (for mac). This problem may happen on other browsers, but I don't use other browsers often.

Here is a screenshot: [image]

note the scroll bar ^

My site is http://www.animefushigi.com

Comment: Check the error console, I get multiple errors, any one of which might be the problem.

Comment: I'm using google chrome for PC and I can't see the error D=

Comment: no white space here either. as @sarnold said, check those errors, and in addition, check browser plugin, extentions if you have any as those can be a cause sometimes.

Comment: FF4 on mac -> no problem

Comment: White space appearing on Chrome 11.0.696.60 - no idea why though.

Comment: Looks good here in FF4, Chrome, IE9.

Comment: Like I said guys, it's random. Most of the time I don't get the whitespace either. I don't know when this will happen but it does happen frequently.

Comment: I saw a lot of whitespace as well.  Got a whole lot of errors as well.  My guess is it's something in your Javascript deciding the height or one of your ads that caused all the errors is freaking out. Update: For me your `#master_wrapper` height is 4496px, but isn't defined in your CSS.  Java?

Comment: Also, at 1024, there is a horizontal scrollbar - assuming you are covering 1024 users

Answer (score 4):

Try `#master_wrapper{overflow:hidden!important;}` in your style sheet :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using captcha. It turns out that captcha's PHP script adds an iframe to your page. My firefox did not display the frame, but safari did. Try and add some css to make possible iframes non visible, that did the trick for my website:

```
iframe { display:none; }
```

Otherwise try "Inspect element" from the menu in Chrome, which should allow you to debug CSS (but not JavaScript). That should though allow you to find the error and you should then be able to change the CSS to make it look nicer.

*PS: Website works great on my Safari & Firefox*

Answer (score 1):

Just add {overflow:hidden;} in css to your main container holding the info.
Worked for me in chrome and firefox :)